# Euro Truck Simulator 2 not installing in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, games

One of my friend send me Euro Truck Simulator 2, whenever I try to install it the following occurs :

```
kapil@kapil-Dell-System-Vostro-3750:~/l$ ./EuroTruckSimulator2.sh
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing Installer for Euro Truck Simulator 2..........
Uncompressing sub archiveWarning: No binaries for "x86_64" found, trying to default to x86...
................................................
Collecting info for this system...
Operating system: linux
CPU Arch: x86
Nixstaller version 0.5.1, Copyright (C) 2006 - 2009 of Rick Helmus
Nixstaller comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
Nixstaller is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the about section for details.
Error opening terminal: xterm.
```

- xterm is installed

Comment: still same error

Comment: Why is nobody answering my question ?

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/terminfo/l
cd /usr/share/terminfo/l
sudo ln -s /lib/terminfo/l/linux linux
export TERM="linux"
```

and try again start game